# Ubuntu 18.04 Change default behaviour of Super+Tab keyboard shortcut

Tags: 18.04, shortcut-keys

I have disabled the keyboard shortcut for switching application.

However, when I create a custom  keyboard shortcut with <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, it does not execute with that combination. Other key combinations works fine.

Is there a workaround?

Comment: i tried Super+Tab for `nautilus` and it is working for it in my Ubuntu 18.04. what are you trying to execute with that combination?

Comment: I tried different things. 'gnome-termial' for example, and a longer script used for changing workspace. Binding it to Super+Z instead works as expected.

Comment: i just tried `gnome-terminal` with Super+Tab it worked..